# SQL - Contar quantidade de registros entre linhas

Tags: mysql, sql

Pessoal preciso de uma ajuda na criação de uma query.
Tenho uma tabela que classifica as pessoas por semana.

```
PessoaId  | Semana  | Grupo 
----------------------------  
1         | 1       | 1   
1         | 2       | 1  
1         | 3       | 1  
1         | 4       | 1    
2         | 1       | 1  
2         | 2       | 2  
2         | 3       | 2
2         | 4       | 1
3         | 1       | 2  
3         | 2       | 2  
3         | 3       | 2
3         | 4       | 2
```

Preciso de uma query para contar quantas semanas elas ficaram fora do grupo 1 e/ou a quantas semanas atras elas estão fora do grupo 1. Isso semana a semana.
Resultado queria mais ou menos assim

```
 
PessoaId  | Semana  | Tempo Fora
----------------------------------  
1         | 1       | 0   
1         | 2       | 0  
1         | 3       | 0  
1         | 4       | 0  
2         | 1       | 0  
2         | 2       | 1  
2         | 3       | 2
2         | 4       | 0
3         | 1       | 1  
3         | 2       | 2  
3         | 3       | 3
3         | 4       | 4
```

Comment: Como saber que a pessoa não está no grupo naquela semana?

Comment: Quando está no grupo 2.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `GROUP BY` junto com um `SUM` e um `IF`.

```
SELECT PessoaId, Semana, SUM(IF(Grupo = 1, 0, 1)) 'Tempo Fora' FROM Classificacao
GROUP BY PessoaId, Semana
```

Nessa `query` assumi que sua tabela de chama `Classificacao`, se não for esse o nome substitua pelo nome correto.

Comment: Cara é quase isso, no Mysql ele funciona de boa, porem no bigquery da google ele não permite que eu faça um agrupamento sem todos os campos que tenho no select

Comment: Então coloca a semana no `GROUP BY` também, vou alterar a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Juliano, se entendi bem, toda vez que o grupo não é igual a 1, conta como falta, para obter esta informação execute a query abaixo, caso não rode, me informe qual plataforma está rodando a própria query:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Faltou durante', PESSOAID as 'Cód. Pessoa' 
  FROM nometabela
  where grupo != 1
  group by pessoaid
```